# How should I get brushes for photoshop that replicate smears of beauty cream? (ageing creme, etc for product shots)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, brush

Can anyone help me with this? How should I get brushes for photoshop that replicate smears of beauty cream? (ageing creme, etc for product shots)

Comment: I'm afraid I'd need to see some sort of sample image.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to have a brush, which looks like the product ? Can you share the image that you want to be replicated by the brush ?

---

***How to create a new brush in photoshop ?***

---

A simple way to do it is just open the image, go to

**Edit>Define Brush Preset**

You may like to edit the image before doing it, like cropping or removing unwanted area